# How to convert a number to alpha character C#

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and need to know how to convert a number to an alpha character. For example if the variable 10 is passed I need to convert 10 to ND and so on.

```
if  0 convert to UH
if 02 convert to IJ
if 10 convert to ND
if 45 convert to YH
if 48 convert to OL
```

I searched for this and could not find what I was looking for.

For further clarification (sorry for not explaining fully)

I have a system passing a numerical value that is equivalent to a alpha value in another system. I am working on an app that allows these two systems to communicate. So I am needing a translation table of sorts that allows me to change the numerical value to the equivalent alpha value. Doing this will allow me to make a soap call with the correct parameters.

Comment: Those appear to be (consistently) random alpha characters. Is there some sort of obvious system that's supposed to map them? Is it ok if it appears random? Does it need to appear random?

Comment: What is the logic of the mapping?

Comment: If it really is a random (but known) relationship, you could use either a dictionary (where the number is the key) or a string array.

Comment: Are you looking for a `Dictionary<int, string>`?

Comment: The alpha characters are defined. I have a program that is passing me the numeric values and I have to convert those values to the alpha equivalent which I use to send a soap request.

Comment: how/where do you have them defined? A Dictionary seems like your best bet

Comment: You won't find what your looking for because noone knows what it is? You need to explain how those values correlate to the alpha values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't see any logic to those, so I'll assume the mapping is external somewhere. Two options - a `switch`, or a dictionary.

```
string result;
switch(num) {
    case 0: result = "UH"; break;
    //...
    case 48: result = "OL"; break;
    default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

or alternatively, a dictionary:

```
static readonly Dictionary<int,string> map = new Dictionary<int,string> {
    {0, "UH"},
    //...
    {48, "OL"}
};
...
string result;
if(!map.TryGetValue(num, out result))
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

---

Edit: a 3rd option - an `enum`:

```
enum Map {
  UH = 0,
  //...
  OL = 48
}
...
Map mapped = (Map)num;
Console.WriteLine(mapped);
// also, string result = mapped.ToString(); if you really need
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one such conversion routine. It doesn't match your outputs, because I don't know what algorithm and/or values you use, besides the ones you showed us.

```
const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJ";
static string ToAlpha(long n)
{
    return new string(n.ToString().Select(x => chars[x - '0']).ToArray());
}
```

It's not especially fast, secret, (i.e. it's a simple code that is easy to figure out, so don't use it as a security mechanism) or compact, (as in, the length of the resulting string) but AFAIK you don't need any of those things. It is, however, dead simple: replace `0` with `A`, `1` with `B`, and so on.

Comment: It is not clear to me that this maps the stated inputs / outputs

Comment: @MarcGravell it doesn't, I'll clarify that.